# TensorFlow Model Restore ValueError - At least two variables have the same name

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I have saved a model and now I am trying to restore it, after restoring it works for the first time correctly but when I press 'TEST' button on the same running program to test another image it gives error

**ValueError: At least two variables have the same name: Variable_2/Adam**

```
def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)#logits

    softMax=tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            logits=prediction, labels=y)#prediction and original comapriosn
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(softMax)#total loss
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)#learning_rate=0.01
    hm_epochs = 20

    new_saver = tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        global s
        s=sess
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('../MY_MODELS/my_MNIST_Model_1.meta')
        new_saver.restore(s, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('../MY_MODELS'))

        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))

        print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval(
            {x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The graph which you have loaded already has all the variables needed for inference. You need to load the tensors like `accuracy` from the saved graph. In your case you have same variables declared outside, which conflicts with the variables in the graph.

During training, if you have named your tensor `accuracy` with a `name='accuracy'`, then you can load it from the graph using: `get_tensor_by_name('accuracy:0')`. In your example, you need to load the input tensors `x` and `y` also from the graph. Your code should be like:

```
def inference():
   loaded_graph = tf.Graph()
   new_saver = tf.train.Saver()
   with tf.Session(graph=loaded_graph) as sess:
       new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('../MY_MODELS/my_MNIST_Model_1.meta')
       new_saver.restore(s, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('../MY_MODELS'))

       #Get the tensors by their variable name 
       # Note: the names of the following tensors have to be declared in your train graph for this to work. So just name them appropriately.
      _accuracy = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('accuracy:0')
      _x  = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('x:0')
      _y  = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('y:0')

       print('Accuracy:', _accuracy.eval(
        {_x: mnist.test.images, _y: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Comment: should training function(saving model) and testing function(restoring model) be different? cant they be a same function?

Comment: They can be same if your training and testing the same time in the same graph. But don't another graph when you are doing that. In your code, remove all the loading of the graph and directly run the accuracy for prediction on the default graph.

Comment: u can see the prediction variable , i am not able to save it in the model, these are the logits that i have to use but i cant save them , please help

Comment: i have made another function for restoring , i need this prediction variable in graph to predict my number

Comment: You can call prediction in the same graph then.